# Javascript Text Selection Range - Word by Word

Tags: javascript, html, css, range, selection

For a `chrome extension` I want to ouput every word of a webpage on a newline. I found code which can provide me with all the text on a webpage:

```
range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(document.body,0);
range.setEnd(document.body,document.body.childNodes.length);
words = range.toString();
```

the variable `words` contains all the text of the webpage. But as far as I know, all the markup is gone because I am not handling any nodes any 
more, but just plain text. How would I go through a range word by word and be able to tell which `css-properties` (for example `font-size`) is used? And weather the word is in someway part of a `<h1>` tag?

Comment: You wouldn't, if you need the markup and styles, don't get a text range ?

Comment: Use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4399718/240443) to get all the text nodes, then you can see where they are in the DOM.